# How To show data groupwise?

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to load order data from different table.

I have displayed data also from tables using `JOIN` query.

This Is my o/p :
[image]

I want something like this :

[image]

The Order ID i.e. No. here should be displayed once, if it repeats.

My JSP Code :

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
                        <%
                            List<String> oIdList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("oIdList");
                            List<String> pNameList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("pNameList");
                            List<String> pQtyList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("pQtyList");
                            List<String> pTimeList = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("pTimeList");
                            List<Boolean> pStatusList = (List<Boolean>)request.getAttribute("statusList");
                        %>
                              <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                      <th width="8%">No.</th>
                                      <th width="23%">Product Name</th>
                                      <th width="20%">Product Qty</th>
                                      <th width="18%">Order Time</th>
                                      <th width="22%"><div align="center">Order Status</div></th>                                          
                                  </tr>
                              </thead>   
                              <tbody>

                              <%
                                    for(int i = 0; i<pNameList.size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        %>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><%= oIdList.get(i) %></td>
                                                <td class="center"><%= pNameList.get(i) %></td>
                                                <td class="center"><%= pQtyList.get(i) %></td>
                                                <td class="center"><%= pTimeList.get(i) %></td>                                             
                                                <%
                                                    if(pStatusList.get(i))
                                                    {

                                                        %>                                                  
                                                            <td class="center"><div align="center"><span class="label label-success">Delivered</span></div></td>
                                                        <% 

                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        %>
                                                            <td style="text-align: center;" width="9%"><span class="label">Pending</span></td>
                                                        <% 

                                                    }
                                                %>

                                            </tr>   
                                        <%
                                    }
                              %>


                              </tbody>
                         </table>
```

So Any Suggestion Please..

Comment: You can add one Jquery code to change value to empty if more than one row for that No. column come same .

Comment: i have corrected code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello. buddy. try this

```
 for(int j =0,i = 0; i<pNameList.size(); i++) {
     %> <tr> <% 
    if(i==0){      
    j++;    
       %> <td><%= j %></td> <%
    }else if(oIdList.get(i) != oIdList.get(i-1)){
    j++;

         %> <td><%= j %></td> <%
    }else{
         %> <td></td> <%

    }    
   %>                                      

  <td class="center"><%= pNameList.get(i) %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= pQtyList.get(i) %></td>
  <td class="center"><%= pTimeList.get(i) %></td>
```

Comment: Sir, Can I print i value ? i.e on place of 11 it's 1 then on place of 9 it's2 and on place of 7 it's 3.

Comment: Sure. to print i value : <%=i %>

Comment: But sir when I am using `<%=i %>` in both condition it gives me like `0,1,..,4,.`  , I want like `1,2,..,3.`

Comment: i have modified this line for(int j =0, i = 0; i<pNameList.size(); i++) {

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable lastIdDisplayed to the id each time around the loop (initialize it to -1 or something else invalid). If lastIdDisplayed == id then don't display id.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not very *object-oriented*. You should convert all these lists of string arrays into **Order** objects.

Then iterate over the Orders (sort them first by using a Comparable interface and comparing on the order id value).

Then use some basic logic to check if the last order id value is the same as the last.